# Asp.Net MVC corrupting hidden while updating database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm learning Asp MVC 5 and facing such issue. Using scaffolding visual studio created for me update controller and view. When editing value I noticed it's using hidden to identify current record. For example:

http://localhost:61551/StoreManager/Edit/6

If you inspect the page using dev tool - you will find a hidden input with a value of "6".

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AlbumId must be a number." data-val-required="The AlbumId field is required." id="AlbumId" name="AlbumId" type="hidden" value="6">
```

In the View we can see that ASP adds code to generate hidden input

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AlbumId)
```

I can easily modify it to any other value and then when I click Save, ASP updates completely different record. So potentially a hacker can easily corrupt all your database. Is there any way to prevent this or use different method or validate it?

Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that's a common way that web-based applications can be badly-designed and full of security flaws.  You would be best-served by studying some best-practices relating to website design.

Comment: You do know that localhost exists only on your machine... We can't see it!

Comment: of course, i thought you guys are familiar with the problem and no need to provide live link

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to *hack* it by just editing the URL instead? e.g. `http://localhost:61551/StoreManager/Edit/7`.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I guess the solution would be to add another column who this record belongs to. And if the user is trying to modify his records - that's fine, otherwise - show error.

Comment: That's why security and ACL topics are exists. Even if an identifier was missing, you still should validate permissions before perform any actions at server side.

Comment: In this case you are using "6" which can easily be changed to "7" or "5". If I encrypt that and store "f$#%$" however, there is very little chance you will know what the "next" id is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that your site trusts whatever input the web browser supplies. This same problem would exist whether the input came via a hidden field, as it does in this case, or through the URL, or some non-hidden field (e.g., you could imagine a UI in which there was a dropdown selector that let you choose which data item you are going to modify) or even if the record was identified in some JSON message sent by JavaScript on the web page to the back end.

So the problem you describe doesn't really have anything to do with the particular detail of this being a hidden field, nor does it have anything to do with the fact that you're using ASP.NET, nor is it peculiar to the way VS scaffolded the app. You could change any of these details and still have the problem, because a malicious user can fake up absolutely anything in a request. Hidden fields are no harder or easier to fake than any other kind of input.

From a security perspective, you need to treat all data that comes in from the client as suspect. The rules for determining whether such input is valid are application-specific, which is why the scaffolded code does not (and cannot) attempt to deal with this.

The only solution is to use some mechanism that lets you determine whether the user who sent the request is allowed to do what the request is asking to do. If you achieve that, it doesn't greatly matter if the end user deliberately changes an ID: if a particular user has permission to edit either the record with id 6 or the record with id 7, then if they edit the 6 and change it to a 7, that's their decision - they're allowed to edit record 7 and have chosen to do so; they've done it in a weird way, but that's their lookout. And if a user has permission to edit 6 but not 7, and they try to change the id to 7, then your server should reject the request with a 403 (Forbidden) response code.

This means you need some way to identify the user (or at least have some way of knowing *something* about them - enough to determine what they have permission to do; in some cases it may be sufficient to know that the user successfully authenticated against some security authority - for some operations, a reasonable security policy may be simply to trust all authenticated users, or all users who belong to a particular security group). And you need some way to decide whether a particular operation is allowed on a particular entity for the user once you have identified them.

Typically, this means making the user log in (and there are all sorts of ways you can do that - your app might run inside some organization that has some sort of single-sign-on system, or perhaps you can defer to an external ID provider like Google, Facebook, or Azure Active Directory, or maybe you could manage accounts yourself - ASP.NET is able to manage user accounts in SQL server for you, for example). And you need to decide how your security policy is actually going to work, and that's such an open-ended thing that I'm not even going to attempt to give exaples, and then you need to write code that enforces that policy.

The basic scaffolded app you got from VS doesn't do all this because there are so many different ways you might approach it. It can do parts of it - you can tell it to configure the app with user account support (e.g., it'll set up SQL Server based account management when you create the project if you want, or it can set it up to use AAD, or single-sign-on through integrated Windows authentication). But it's still your job to decide what sort of security policy you want. If you want a very basic model of, say, "This is only accessible to authenticated users", then you can put the `[Authorize]` custom attribute on a controller. But if you want entity-level security (e.g., rules that determine who is allowed to modify any particular entity) then you'll need to write code to make that happen.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of ways to deal with this. One such way is to use [User roles](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97) to limit who can access various methods (like Edit).

You could have snippets like:

```
if (User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
{
    // TODO
}
```

Or you can use [Authorize attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.roles(v=vs.118).aspx) like so:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    // TODO
}
```

Alternatively, these can also be placed on specific methods inside a controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
public ActionResult Edit(Album model)
{
    // TODO
}
```

These are better solutions for when you have broadly defined roles over who can access what, but suppose you have a service where each user can log in and manage his own items. You can also add a field to the model/table to denote the person who that item belongs to, e.g.:

```
if (albumModel.UserName == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
{
    // allow user to edit if it is his item
}
```

You can also see how you might combine these, e.g. if an admin is allowed to edit the user's album, you can first check if the user belongs to the admin role, otherwise check if it is this user's album, etc.

Comment: This is solving my problem 100%. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @Vadym No problem. Just FYI though, I think you tried, but you can only check one answer. Happy to help though.

Comment: that's true. Both answers are good but unfortunately can't select both :)